# Framer Motion Does not Loop

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to loop an animation with the Framer Motion library after a small delay. The animation itself will play when it's mounted, on the webpage refresh, however does not repeat. Iv'e looked through the docs and this seems to be similar syntax.

```
const AnimateTrial = {
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: -100,
    y: -35,
    scale: 0.9,
  },
  animate: (i) => {
    const delay = 5 + i * 0.5;
    return {
      opacity: 1,
      x: -10,
      y: -35,

      transition: {
        opacity: { delay, duration: 1.5 },
        x: { delay, duration: 1.5},
        repeatType: "Infinity",
        repeatDelay: 5,
      },
    };
  }
```

I have also tried passing:

```
transition={{ repeat: Infinity, repeatDelay: 5 }}
```

But am yet to have it work. Any ideas!

I can confirm the remainder of the animation works, but it does not loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having never laid eyes upon a `transition` object nested inside an `animate` function, I had to take this to code sandbox.

I'm new to Framer Motion myself but there are multiple things that strike me as odd and how I would fix them:

1. Setting a duration on several properties within `transition`. I don't believe this is a supported feature, so I'm moving it for this answer as both your `opacity` and `x` properties share the same `duration`.

```
transition: {
    duration: 1.5,
    opacity: delay,
    x: delay,
    repeatType: "Infinity",
    repeatDelay: 5
}
```

2. Setting a `repeatType` without a `repeat` will not loop the animation. Setting `repeat: Infinite` will ([and you can drop the `repeatType`](https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/###repeat)).

```
transition: {
    duration: 1.5,
    opacity: delay,
    x: delay,
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatDelay: 5
}
```

Note that we still do not have a repeating animation.

3. Using animate as a function. I'm not sure, but I think the entire function might only get evaluated once and immediately discarded. I believe that the second time Framer Motion looks at the `delay` value it fails, thus not animating that specific property. (I am also not sure what you are trying to achieve with using `delay` inside the `x` and `opacity` properties.)

If we change *either* the `opacity` or `x` to use `0` as a value rather than `delay`, you can see that it will behave as expected - whereas the unchanged property only animates once. Changing them both will display the looping behavior you are looking for:

```
transition: {
    duration: 1.5,
    opacity: 0,
    x: 0,
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatDelay: 5
}
```

Thus, we've reached our final code:

```
const AnimateTrial = {
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: -100,
    y: -35,
    scale: 0.9
  },
  animate: (i) => {
    const delay = 5 + i * 0.5; // (now unused)
    return {
      opacity: 1,
      x: -10,
      y: -35,

      transition: {
        duration: 1.5,
        opacity: 0,
        x: 0,
        repeat: Infinity,
        repeatDelay: 5
      }
    };
  }
};
```

[Here's a live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animation-looping-t4nou?file=/src/App.js) showcasing the working animation loop. (I changed `repeatDelay` to `1` for testing speed purposes).

Comment: Thankyou so much Codestrife, you've saved my life on this one 100% appreciate everything! Thankyou thankyou